# Connecting smartphone to pc if the phone is locked

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, motorola, usb-debugging

I read that i can use USB Debugging and adb to copy my phone data even if its is locked .But my Ubuntu -14.10 does not  detect the smartphone unless i unlock it.Any suggestions ?

Tried both Usb 2.0 and 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. There is option in the developer options of settings that says "Stay awake".

Also you can keep it unlocked by settings>security>Screen lock>none

Comment: thank your for the answer ,it worked finally. Actually i wanted to find a way to copy all my data in case my screen stops working again as it did today coz of a bug in update ,so i had to hard reset and i lost all my daya